# Join a dynamic number of futures

Tags: rust

[`join!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/future/macro.join.html) can join multiple async operations:

```
#![feature(future_join)]

use std::future::join;

async fn one() -> usize { 1 }
async fn two() -> usize { 2 }

let x = join!(one(), two()).await;
assert_eq!(x, (1, 2));
```

Is there a way to join multiple futures from a vector, such that the number of async calls is dynamic (unknown at compile time)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`join_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.25/futures/future/fn.join_all.html) from the futures crate.

From the docs:

> ```rust
> use futures::future::join_all;
>
> async fn foo(i: u32) -> u32 { i }
>
> let futures = vec![foo(1), foo(2), foo(3)];
>
> assert_eq!(join_all(futures).await, [1, 2, 3]);
> ```

Comment: Is the `join` macro more efficient or why should you not always use this function instead of the macro?

Comment: @leo848 The macro returns a tuple, so it can be used with futures that return different types. `join_all` takes and returns an array, so the results must be the same type.